# How to turn JPEG code for API GET request into rendered image in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, binary, base64, jpeg

I'm running a GET API request in React to get a JPEG image from an API. Here's what the returned JPEG code looks like:

```
����JFIF��� ( %!1!%)+...!683-7(-.+



/% %-/-/-2-----./-.-----/-----/-----------------------���"����A!1AQ"aq�2����B�3Rr��#4b����Cs����c����2!1Aq2Q��3a�"�����#4D����?q�)��Lz��
�Le0���`��Sh����&j�,�xOQ� ��S�r@����օ��
�*�?��վ���.�-i�5WJU�H"�d�>�D9�Z��Ȟ��O�!�'��i��s�#�9�Js�@K�Y\�b�4 )d&�!JK��K*�r!,�x˔Ǵ¾���� 9.������Ed�R�� �

and on and on...
```

I then use btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(res.data))) to convert that JPEG code into Base64. This is what the Base64 looks like:

```
77+977+977+977+9ABBKRklGAAEBAAABAAEAAO+/ve+/vQDvv70ACQYHExMSFRISExUWFRYYGRoYFxcYFhgYGx4YGxoXGhcZGhoeKCAYGiUbGxohMSElKSsuLi4dITY4My03KC0uKwEKCgoODQ4bEBAbLyUgJS0vLS8tMi0tLS0tLi8tLi0tLS0tLy0tLS0tLy0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0t77+977+9ABEIAO+/vQEcAwEiAAIRAQMRAe+/ve+/vQAbAAADAAMBAQAAAAAAAAAAAAADBAUAAgYBB++/ve+/vQBBEAABAgUDAgMGAg...

and on and on....
```

I then put the Base64 into an img tag like this:

```
<img src={`data:image/jpeg;base64,${base64}`}/>
```

I don't get any error codes, but my image is blank. The image does not appear. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you just put the api url in the `img` `src` rather than getting it with an ajax request?

Comment: No, because the API requires a username and password to access the images. The only way to do that is with a GET request passing in the credentials with the request.

Comment: It depends how you're requesting the image. If you're just using `fetch`, then you can use `response.blob()` to read the response as a data Blob, and `URL.createObjectURL` to get a local object URL representing that data. Assign that object URL to the src of the image and voila, you're done.

Comment: I'm using axios because I have to pass in a username and password in the GET request to gain access to the JPEG. I tried some new things, but it's still not working. I updated the code above. Would you know how to fix it?